# Найти скрипт, в котором объявлена переменная/объект

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

На сайте есть куча скриптов. Один из скриптов использует объект, который находится в глобальной области видимости. Как с помощью консоли найти скрипт(файл), в котором объявлен этот объект?

Comment: никак, открывайте каждый и поиском

Comment: @torokhkun, плохо. Не хотелось искать таким способом)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предположение - сайт доступен для редактирования, и в начало страницы можно вставить вот такой скрипт.

Работает в Firefox, который поддерживает событие `afterscriptexecute`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/afterscriptexecute

```html
<script>
  var found = false;
  document.addEventListener("afterscriptexecute", function(e) {
    if (e.target.src) {
      console.log("Loaded: ", e.target.src)
      if (!found && window.jQuery) {
        console.log("This script defines jQuery.");
        found = true;
      }
    }
  });
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.6/d3.min.js"></script>

test
```

Если сайт нет возможности редактировать - нужно остановить страницу отладчиком (в Инструментах Разработчика браузера) на первой исполняемой строке кода страницы и назначить обработчик, выполнив скрипт в консоли.

Comment: Не решение, но плюс поставил только за знание...)))

Comment: Прикольно. Как написано в руководстве: `The afterscriptexecute event is fired after a script has been executed.` Это означает, что событие возникает не только после загрузки скрипта, но и после каждого исполнения (даже его части). Например, при отработке обработчика. Я правильно понял?  П.С: "Прикольно" 
 = "Потрясающе"

Comment: @Дмытрык Нет, имеется в виду однократное выполнение кода внутри тэга `script` - с указанием js файла или без него - после загрузки. И что значит "прикольно"? Здесь уместно определение "потрясающе".